# How to express the accuracy of RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I have been expressing the RandomForestRegressor accuracy based on MAPE as below and surprisingly I get the accuracy of more than 90%.

```
def get_accuracy(model,X_test, y_test):
    pred = model.predict(X_test)
    errors = abs(pred - y_test)
    MSE=round(np.mean(errors),2)
    MAPE=100*(errors/y_test)
    accuracy=round (100 - np.mean(MAPE),2)
    return accuracy
```

A colleague of mine, however, uses RandomForestRegressor().score() as the measure of the accuracy. For the same dataset and model, the score from the model is <80% while the MAPE is >90%.  Can someone explain which one represents the true accuracy of the model?

Comment: Have you checked this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327464/mape-vs-r-squared-in-regression-models ?

Comment: @hellpanderr-thanks for the link but it still does not give me a simple answer which one to choose